# Can I tell linq 2 SQL not to update certain columns after attachment or use of UpdateModel?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Let's assume I have the following situation, the update method in my service accepts a model (the one that is going to be updated) as an input parameter. The model can be unattached (in which case attach method is called before submitting changes) or attached (in which case we just submit changes). Edit actions just call this update method in my service. Now let's assume I cannot change the code in those actions (the code that produces the model to be updated). Can I still somehow prevent certain columns from updating from within the update method. Note that I might want to set those columns using linq to SQL, but only during insert method.

I'm quite sure I'm trying something unconventional here, but it might help me write some easy to reuse code. If it cannot be done, then I'll solve it differently, but it never hurts to try something new.

Answer (score 0):

The `Attach` method does provide an override to accept both a modified and original entity.
[Attach Modified Entity on Data Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548972(v=vs.110).aspx)

When using this the internal change tracker will figure out which columns have been updated and will only update those ones on the datasource which have changed, rather than updating all columns.

Alternatively if you want more explicit control over which properties are updated, you can reattach your entity as unmodified in its original state:
[Attach Modified/Unmodified Entity on Data Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548778(v=vs.110).aspx)

This will hook up the internal change tracker to the PropertyChanging events on the entity so it can be tracked.  You would then simply change the values of the properties on that entity in the `Update` method on your Service.

```
    void Update(MyModel model)
    {
        using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            ctx.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
            ctx.MyEntities.Attach(model.OriginalEntity);
            model.OriginalEntity.Value = model.ModifiedEntity.Value;
            ctx.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

The pitfall of these approaches means you must maintain both the original and modified entities in your model, but could be set when your entities are loaded - a simple shallow copy of the object should do the trick by deriving from `ICloneable` in a partial class for each entity.